# Add to locals() in Python 3.2+?

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x

I'm trying to programmatically define several variables in the local namespace:

```
for build_step in 'prepare', 'configure', 'make', 'stage', 'package', 'all':
    p = build_subparsers.add_parser(build_step)
    p.set_defaults(build_step=build_step)
    if build_step != 'package':
        p.add_argument('specfile')
    locals()['build_'+build_step+'_parser'] = p
build_prepare_parser
```

```
NameError: global name 'build_prepare_parser' is not defined
```

However after running this code, none of the variables I presumed to create actually exist despite appearing in `locals()`. How do I do this in Python 3.2?

### Update0

I know `locals()` is a bad idea, that's why I'm asking this question.

Comment: ["Note: The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter."](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#locals)

Comment: This is a really bad way of doing this, Why are you editing locals like this, why so many variables. Use a list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is: don't do that.

If you want to programmatically store values, use a container:

```
>>> d = dict()
>>> d['a'] = 5
```

Or create a container class, if you really must.

```
>>> class Container(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> c = Container()
>>> setattr(c, 'a', 5)
>>> c.a
5
```

Comment: See [here](http://ideone.com/bYLZN) for a slightly more sophisticated container class.

Answer (score 5):

Why not give build it's own namespace?

```
class Build(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self

build = Build()
for build_step in 'prepare', 'configure', 'make', 'stage', 'package', 'all':
    p = build_subparsers.add_parser(build_step)
    p.set_defaults(build_step=build_step)
    if build_step != 'package':
        p.add_argument('specfile')
    build[build_step+'_parser'] = p
build.prepare_parser
```

Comment: I like this one... but somehow the `self.__dict__ = self` thing makes me feel funny inside. What if you did [this](http://ideone.com/bYLZN)?

Comment: @senderle, sure, that would work. You could also add nice `__repr__` etc to the class

Answer (score -1):

According to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/functions.html#locals) for locals():

> The contents of this dictionary should
>   not be modified; changes may not
>   affect the values of local and free
>   variables used by the interpreter.

Try putting them in globals() (which is the symbol dictionary for the current module, not truly global.)