# Python Pandas Read multiple SAS files from a list into separate dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading a bunch of SAS files like so:

`demography = pd.read_sas("demography.sas7bdat", encoding = 'latin-1')
adverse_event_ds = pd.read_sas("adverse_event_ds.sas7bdat", encoding = 'latin-1') 
rpt10344 = pd.read_sas("rpt10344.sas7bdat", encoding = 'latin-1')
vaccine_administration = pd.read_sas("vaccine_administration.sas7bdat", encoding = 'latin-1')
lab_tests_blood_chemistry_ds = pd.read_sas("lab_tests_blood_chemistry_ds.sas7bdat", encoding = 'latin-1') 
lab_tests_hematology_ds = pd.read_sas("lab_tests_hematology_ds.sas7bdat", encoding = 'latin-1')
lab_tests_miscellaneous_ds = pd.read_sas("lab_tests_miscellaneous_ds.sas7bdat", encoding = 'latin-1') 
vital_signs = pd.read_sas("vital_signs.sas7bdat", encoding = 'latin-1')`

I want to be able to replace it with something like this:

`datasets = ["demography", "adverse_event_ds", "rpt10344", "vaccine_administration", "lab_tests_blood_chemistry_ds", "lab_tests_hematology_ds", "lab_tests_miscellaneous_ds", "vital_signs"]`

`for dataset in datasets:
    dataset = pd.read_sas(dataset+".sas7bdat", encoding = 'latin-1')`

But when I do something like: 
`demography.info()`

I get:
`NameError: name 'demography' is not defined`

What's happening under the hood and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is assigning to `dataset` on every iteration rather than creating the new variables (e. g. `demography`, `rpt10344`, etc).

i'd use a dataset dictionary as follows:

```
dsd = {}
for dataset in datasets:
    dsd[dataset] = pd.read_sas(dataset+".sas7bdat", encoding = 'latin-1')
```

or a more pythonic route:

```
dsd = { d : pd.read_sas(d + ".sas7bdat", encoding = 'latin-1') for d in datasets }
```

I'd strongly advise against assigning to individual variable names for reasons explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-via-a-while-loop) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47109931/python-pandas-dynamically-create-a-dataframe) but if you absolutely must you can use

```
for d in datasets:
    globals()[d] = pd.read_sas(d + ".sas7bdat", encoding = 'latin-1')
```

Comment: Thanks! This did help, but how can I have the dataframes assigned directly to the name, rather than having to do something like `dsd["demography"]`?

Comment: It's better practice to have the dataframes in a container like a dictionary: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6365889/5666087

Comment: Thanks for that and the links! This really helped explain why it's a bad idea! Thanks a lot!

Comment: no prob! please consider accepting my answer if it worked for you.

Comment: @tbdees - I hit a +1 on your answer, does that count as accepting or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @TheCuriouslyCodingFoxah if you click the checkmark it should change color - more information on that here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :)